# SQL: Find discontinuities in temporal data

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a dataset where I have to find gaps in the temporal columns and show what happened before and after each section for each person in the list.

- If nothing was present in the day before valid_from, I want a 0, and if something was present, I want whatever was present.
- If nothing was present the day after valid_to, I want a 0.

See the example below, where person XXX starts in G1 and moves to G2 with only 1 day between. Hence old_value = 0 and new_value is G1 followed by old_value = G1 and new_value = G2.

It should never happen that valid_to next valid_from for the same person_id

Input data:

| id | person_id | current_value | valid_from | valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | XXX | G1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 |
| 2 | XXX | G2 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-03-01 |
| 3 | YYY | G1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-01 |
| 4 | YYY | G3 | 2022-02-02 | 2022-03-01 |
| 5 | YYY | G1 | 2022-04-01 | 2022-04-30 |
| 6 | ZZZ | G2 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-31 |

Expected result:

| person_id | old_value | new_value | valid_from |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | 0 | G1 | 2022-01-01 |
| XXX | G1 | G2 | 2022-02-02 |
| XXX | G2 | 0 | 2022-03-02 |
| YYY | 0 | G1 | 2022-01-01 |
| YYY | G1 | G3 | 2022-02-02 |
| YYY | G3 | 0 | 2022-02-03 |
| YYY | 0 | G1 | 2022-04-01 |
| YYY | G1 | 0 | 2022-05-01 |
| ZZZ | 0 | G2 | 2022-01-01 |
| ZZZ | G2 | 0 | 2022-02-01 |

What have been tried so far: Self joins and various filters, but that does not catch the case with ZZZ.
Also tried some magic with LAG in an inner query, but no success.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How do you handle "yyy" with G1 > G3 > G1, what's the criteria?